# iPad UIInterfaceOrientation after launch image

Tags: ipad, rotation, launch, uiinterfaceorientation, launching-application

My application should support only landescape mode, so I configure the info.plist keys to get it in the right way.
My root viewcontroller is a custom UINavigationController that I add to the main window and which implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

The problem is that, after applicationDidFinishLaunching, `interfaceOrientation` is always UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight even when the application was launched in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft orientation.
The result is that the splash image is oriented properly, while the application is upsidedown.
Shaking the device for a while, make the controller rotate again in the correct direction.

Is it a bug? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {

  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {

  return YES;

  }else{

  return NO;

  }

  }

Good luck

Comment: This is the same has my code. The problem is not the if statament, but interfaceOrientation that should be interfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, instead of interfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.